# Adding Blocks within Blocks

Tags: posts

Not sure if this specific question has been asked before. So regret repeating it here again.

**My WP version: 6.2**

**My usecase** -- I am unable to add blocks within blocks. Mostly I do not get option to add other core and custom blocks **most commonly inside list items**.

Is there a way to remove this restriction (*via code change or plugin*) to allow any block to be added within other blocks?

Comment: Currently facing the same issue in WordPress 6.4.1 especially while trying to edit a loop template.

Comment: this isn't something supported by core at the moment, the core/list block would need to be adjusted. I'd recommend raising a github issue on `wordpress/gutenberg` or adding your support to an existing issue if one exists

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about **nested Gutenberg blocks**, you only need to add the InnerBlocks component.

I think this is what you're looking for :

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/

Here you have all the code you need and most of the use cases.

Hope it helps !